# Adding local.css into header from local.xml

Tags: css, xml, magento

I have a strange problem i think. Usually i add custom styling sheets into head with following code:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type><name>css/local.css</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

But on custom theme i am working on, this add local.css into base package like this:

```
/skin/frontend/base/default/css/local.css
```

I want it to be like this:

```
/skin/frontend/default/mytheme/css/local.css
```

This is my settings from admin panel:
[image]

What am i missing here?

Comment: Have you checked the skin url setting for the store in the backend?

Comment: You should set package name (default) and theme name (mytheme) in the admin panel.

Comment: @Mr_Green i have updated with image from my settings.

Comment: Did you try: `<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/local.css</stylesheet></action>`?

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes i have also tried that syntax, but with same result. Still getting base package :(